# jQuery ajax request of page with redirect, redirects my entire page.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, get

I'm retrieving a html page using jQuery `$.get` method and then append the result to a div.

The page I am retrieving page redirects to another page (after 3 seconds), but this causes my parent page to redirect, not the `#mentions` as I want.

```
$.get("index.php", {
    act: "Search", 
    CODE: 01, 
    keywords: nickName, 
    exactname: 1, 
    joinname: 1, 
    cat_forum: "forum", 
    forums: "all", 
    searchsubs: 1, 
    search_in: "posts", 
    result_type: "posts", 
    prune: 30, 
    prune_type: "newer", 
    sort_key: "last_post", 
    sort_order: "desc" 
}, function(data) { 
    $("#mentions").append(data); 
}, "html");
```

Comment: just a guess (because there is not enough information to actually help you) you are still submitting the page/form. probably a missing `return false;`

Comment: Are you appending the whole html page to the div? Add your javascript code to the post.

Comment: @rlemon thanks for fast reply. Here's the code
$.get("index.php", {act: "Search", CODE: 01, keywords: nickName, exactname: 1, joinname: 1, cat_forum: "forum", forums: "all", searchsubs: 1, search_in: "posts", result_type: "posts", prune: 30, prune_type: "newer", sort_key: "last_post", sort_order: "desc"}, function(data) {
 $("#mentions").append(data);
}, "html");

every thing's working just fine, data succesfully appends to div, but when data (html doc) inside #mentions div redirects to another page (after 3 secs), redirected page doesn't stay inside the div

Comment: @Slev7n OKAY I think I understand your issue now. simple answer is not to use a div, they are not iframes. It sounds like you want to use an iframe here. If you are focused on using the div, the redirect can't be a redirect. you need to call that ajax function and replace the contents of the div again. But like I said at the start, iframes are likely what you are looking for.

Comment: @rlemon I replaced div with iframe, same result :(

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to get only the insides of the body:

```
$.get("index.php", {
    act: "Search",
    CODE: 01,
    keywords: nickName,
    exactname: 1,
    joinname: 1,
    cat_forum: "forum",
    forums: "all",
    searchsubs: 1,
    search_in: "posts",
    result_type: "posts",
    prune: 30,
    prune_type: "newer",
    sort_key: "last_post",
    sort_order: "desc"
}, function (data) {
    $("#mentions").append($(data).find("body").html());
}, "html");
```

Note: If you have specific javascript and css in index.php that needs to run this wouldn't work, for that you need an iframe.

Comment: Consol displays the following error: 
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Comment: that's odd not getting any syntax error here, just change $("#mentions").append(data);  with $("#mentions").append($(data).find("body").html());